# Django ALLOWED_HOSTS with ELB HealthCheck

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have a django application deployed on Elastic Beanstalk. The HealthCheck for my app keeps failing because the IP of the ELB HealthCheck is not included in my `ALLOWED_HOSTS` settings variable.

How can I modify `ALLOWED_HOSTS` to make the HealthCheck pass? I would just pass in the explicit IP address, but I believe that this changes, so whenever the IP changes the check would fail again until I add the new IP.

Comment: Any luck yet? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: I just hard coded the IP address. Worked for as long as I had the site running, anyways

Answer (score 40):

Here is another solution using Django Middleware.

Django's `django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware` calls `request.get_host()`, which validates the request with `ALLOWED_HOSTS`. If you simply want to check that the application is running, you can create a middleware like this.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


class HealthCheckMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if request.path == '/health':
            return HttpResponse('ok')
        return self.get_response(request)
```

And put your `HealthCheckMiddleware` in front of `CommonMiddleware` in `settings.py`

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'yourdjangoapp.middleware.HealthCheckMiddleware',
    ......
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ......
]
```

And your application will always respond to path `/health` with `ok` as long as your app is running regardless of any configurations.

Comment: This seems like a fine solution to me!

Comment: This works well. Also suitable for Route53 http healthchecks. May consider adding checks against user-agent strings expected to be sent by AWS HTTP health checks.

Comment: I love this solution! Very elegant compared to the other answer.

Comment: Should this also be before `SecurityMiddleware`? I think that's the layer that verifies `ALLOWED_HOSTS`?

Answer (score 23):

Your EC2 instance can query [metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-retrieval) about itself, including its IP address which is available at: http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4.

You can test this by ssh-ing into your EC2 instance and running:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4
```

So, in your configuration, you can do something like:

```
import requests

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.yourdomain.com', ]
try:
    EC2_IP = requests.get('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4').text
    ALLOWED_HOSTS.append(EC2_IP)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
    pass
```

Obviously you can replace `requests` with `urllib` if you don't want the dependency.

Comment: This would not work in this case because the user is trying to get the IP address of the ELB, not the server they are running on. The above code code doesn't get the IP address of the ELB.

Comment: It does work because when the ELB runs its health check, the IP is that of the server, not the ELB

Comment: Note that with an ELB _network_ load balancer, HTTP health checks won't work with this method because the HTTP host header [contains the IP address of the load balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html#host-header-mismatch). `The HTTP host header in the health check request contains the IP address of the load balancer node and the listener port, not the IP address of the target and the health check port`

Comment: What's with the magic `169.254.169.254` ip address?

Comment: It's a magic address to get instance metadata: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html

Answer (score 6):

### Solution

The solution that worked for me was to simply install the [django-ebhealthcheck](https://github.com/sjkingo/django-ebhealthcheck) library. After installing it, just add `ebhealthcheck.apps.EBHealthCheckConfig` to your INSTALLED_APPS.

From django-ebhealthcheck GitHub:

> By default, Elastic Beanstalk's health check system uses the public IP
> of each load balanced instance as the request's host header when
> making a request. Unless added to ALLOWED_HOSTS, this causes Django to
> return a 400 Bad Request and a failed health check.
>
> This app dynamically adds your instance's public IP address to
> Django's ALLOWED_HOSTS setting to permit health checks to succeed.
> This happens upon application start.
>
> Version 2.0.0 and higher supports IMDSv2. If you are using v1 and
> cannot upgrade, use version 1 of this library instead (pip install
> django-ebhealthcheck<2.0.0).

---

### Installation

1. `pip install django-ebhealthcheck`
2. Add `ebhealthcheck.apps.EBHealthCheckConfig` to your INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'ebhealthcheck.apps.EBHealthCheckConfig',
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 3):

To expand on [the answer provided by dfrdmn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33527496/5747944):

While this answer works well in most cases, it has a couple small potential problems.

### AWS ELB Network Load Balancers

First, if you are using an ELB *network* load balancer, this method won't work with its HTTP health checks because the load balancer sends the IP address of the *load balancer* in the HTTP host header. From [the AWS  docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html#host-header-mismatch):

> The HTTP host header in the health check request contains the IP address of the load balancer node and the listener port, not the IP address of the target and the health check port. If you are mapping incoming requests by host header, you must ensure that health checks match any HTTP host header. Another option is to add a separate HTTP service on a different port and configure the target group to use that port for health checks instead. Alternatively, consider using TCP health checks.

So, adding your instance (target group) IP to your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` will not work. As stated, you could use TCP health checks, or you could use the middleware approach described in another answer.

### Metadata endpoint is throttled

Second, because the metadata endpoint limits number of concurrent connections and [throttles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html#instancedata-throttling) requests, you may encounter issues in some cases.

Your Django `settings.py` file is executed for *every* process and any time processes need to restart. This is important if your webserver is configured to use multiple processes, such as when using [gunicorn workers](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#worker-processes), as is commonly configured to properly take full advantage of system CPU resources.

This means that, with enough processes, your `settings.py` file will be executed many times, sending many concurrent requests to the metadata endpoint and your processes could fail to start. Further, on subsequent process restarts, the throttling will exacerbate the throttling problem. In some circumstances, this can cause your application to grind to a halt or have fewer processes running than intended.

To get around this, you could do a few things:

1. Obtain the IP address *before* starting your server and set the IP address as an environment variable, then read the environment variable to add it to your allowed hosts.

```
$ export ALLOWED_HOST_EC2_PRIVATE_IP=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)
$ gunicorn -w 10 ... myapp:app
```

```py
# settings.py

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['myhost.tld', ]

if os.getenv('ALLOWED_HOST_EC2_PRIVATE_IP'):
    ALLOWED_HOSTS.append(os.environ['ALLOWED_HOST_EC2_PRIVATE_IP'])
```

You may yet still encounter throttling issues with the metadata endpoint if many applications or other services utilize the instance's metadata at the same time.

2. For services running in containers on ECS you can use the [container metadata file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/container-metadata.html)

You can do this safely within the `settings.py` because there is no throttling or rate limit for accessing this file. This also avoids your application potentially interfering with other services that need the instance's metadata endpoint.

```py
# settings.py
import os
import json

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['myhost.tld', ]

if os.getenv('ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_FILE'):
    metadata_file_path = os.environ['ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_FILE']
    with open(metadata_file_path) as f:
        metadata = json.load(f)
    private_ip = metadata["HostPrivateIPv4Address"]
    ALLOWED_HOSTS.append(private_ip)
```

You could also combine the first approach with the metadata file, in your container's ENTRYPOINT.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# docker-entrypoint.sh
export ALLOWED_HOST_EC2_PRIVATE_IP=$(jq -r .HostPrivateIPv4Address $ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_FILE)

exec "$@"
```

```
FROM myapplication
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["gunicorn", "whatever"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I like [Watt Imsuri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6457840/watt-iamsuri)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64623669/10856743) above, and I think I'm going to use this approach in all my projects so I turned it into a pip package for Django.

```
pip install django-easy-health-check
```

Add the health check middleware to Django settings before `django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware`:

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...,
    'easy_health_check.middleware.HealthCheckMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

By default, the health check url will be available at "example.com/healthcheck/".

You can also customize and overwrite the default settings by including the following in your project's settings.py:

```py
DJANGO_EASY_HEALTH_CHECK = {
    "PATH": "/healthcheck/",
    "RETURN_STATUS_CODE": 200,
    "RETURN_BYTE_DATA": "",
    "RETURN_HEADERS": None
}
```

In production, you may also want to set the following Django settings:

```py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["example.com"]
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT = [r'^healthcheck/$']
```

For more info, check out the [git](https://github.com/oscarychen/django-easy-health-check).

Comment: This is a great, platform-agnostic approach, as long as you accept the (minute) security risks of not validating the HTTP_HOST header on these probes

Answer (score -1):

The other solution doesn't answer the question because it doesn't take into consideration all the various tools AWS has (ELB, etc). What we ended up doing (since we use `nginx` + `uwsgi`) is we set the header to something valid when the user sends a request.

As documented on this page:

https://opbeat.com/blog/posts/the-new-django-allowed_hosts-with-elb-uwsgi-and-nginx/

We put our `nginx` configuration as below:

```
set $my_host $host;
if ($host ~ "\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+") {
  set $my_host "example.com";
}

location / {
  uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/mysite.com.sock;
  uwsgi_param HTTP_HOST $my_host;
  include uwsgi_params;
}
```

The key here is to put a valid value for `$my_host` as per your `ALLOWED_HOSTS`.

Unfortunately there is no "perfect" solution without increasing overhead. Some configurations will require you to add IP addresses all the time to the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` but this solution would generally work with the least over head.

Comment: Isn't this effectively the same as allowing *?

Comment: @Kevin kind of, but it's not _exactly_ the same. It still poses the same risks, albeit minimized somewhat. This configuration would prevent sending bad host headers with anything other than an IP address. However, the attack vector that host header checking prevents is still vulnerable if an attacker spoofs the header with a rogue IP address, rather than a rogue DNS name. So, this method shouldn't be recommended for that reason. Not to mention, it would break the functionality that relies on the host header.