# Django allowed_hosts issue deploying to AWS Elastic Beanstalk (DisallowedHost exception)

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my dockerized django app to Elastic, but I keep getting a DisallowedHost exception:

```
django         | Traceback (most recent call last):
django         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
django         |     response = get_response(request)
django         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 135, in __call__
django         |     response = self.process_request(request)
django         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 48, in process_request
django         |     host = request.get_host()
django         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 148, in get_host
django         |     raise DisallowedHost(msg)
django         | django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '10.1.XX.XXX'. You may need to add '10.1.XX.XXX' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

I am not sure what the ip relates to but it is different everytime I try to deploy.

my settings:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['my.domain', 'xxx.ap-southeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com']
```

I have tried adding the EC2 private ip dynamically following this answer (2nd answer not the accepted one):
[ALLOWED_HOSTS not working in my Django App deployed to Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55433886/allowed-hosts-not-working-in-my-django-app-deployed-to-elastic-beanstalk)

Similarly this way:
[Django ALLOWED_HOST setting for Elastic beanstalk instance behind Elastic Load Balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34428877/django-allowed-host-setting-for-elastic-beanstalk-instance-behind-elastic-load-b)

I've also tried this answer to create custom middleware:
[Django ALLOWED_HOSTS with ELB HealthCheck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27720254/django-allowed-hosts-with-elb-healthcheck)

When I set allowed hosts to '*' it successfully deploys.